# Camera bt656 without i2c. How capture?

Tags: linux-device-driver, video-capture, i2c

I have camera (camera + videoprocessor TW8834) sending video data over bt656 protocol, but the camera interface have not i2c on cable, so, it isn't recognizing by linux video driver.Is there some way to capture video from my camera in linux without modifieng the video driver?

I got advice to make a fake probe in the existing video driver (sun6i), but i don't think that it is the optimal way.  May be i can write some driver or something simmilar that will snap up i2c messaging with my camera? Can i use it with default video driver by this way?
May be, are there  some other way?

What should i learn to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by driver and DeviceTree modification. OS Armbian, easy to build, easy to make and apply patches. Big community. Some course about kernel hacking, which was usefull for me: https://courses.linuxchix.org/kernel-hacking-2002.html
For create solution we with my collegue spend about 4 days, we both was non-experienced in kernel modification earlier. I hope, this information will help someone with similar problem.